# How to automate NUnit tests in an ASP.NET website project?

Tags: asp.net, testing, web, nunit, continuous

I have a client who has a large existing application written in ASP.NET, which is setup as a *website* project in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

I have been asked to demonstrate how to write unit tests and to help configure the Hudson build environment to run these tests automatically.

The code is reasonably well structured and although it does not use any UI patterns there is good separation. Business logic tends to sit inside separate classes rather than within the .aspx or associated code-behind files.

Nevertheless, as a website project rather than a web application, DLLs are not generated so the tests we have written cannot be run by the NUnit GUI.

I would like to be able to run the tests before check-in.
I would like to run the tests automatically as part of the continuous build process.
I cannot change the project type to a web application as there are downstream processes that are dependent on the project type.
Whilst upgrading to Visual Studio Professional is being investigated, I have to assume for the purpose of this exercise that I will need to make it work on VWD.

What are my options to achieve this, given the constraints above? Is it even possible?

TIA